# Is it professionally accepted to apply for jobs after accepting an offer

Tags: job-offer, applications

In my field of work, for some reason, the hiring companies all put out their job offers at the same time (within a few days of each other), and do the hiring during the same period in the case of students fresh out of college applying for jobs. This might be because most companies offer to pay for Professional exams that we have to take in the first years of employement after we're done with University, so it might be some sort of agreement because of competition. I'm not familiar with the why.

This phenomenon is happening across the country, but that specific time period differs depending on the location.

In my case, I currently live with my parents in city A, where I have gone to university. City A has several companies that hire in my field, but not that many. I will be graduating in spring, and the offers in my city will be available in December. Since I was not 100% certain I'd be able to get a job on my first try, and I didn't want to live off my parents when I'm done with school, I also applied with several employers in city B, which is about 3 hours (car) from here, and a much bigger city. I am not a fan of big cities, so I would much rather work in city A, but I wouldn't mind moving to city B if the alternative is no work. The problem is that city B released all their offers recently. I applied, did a few interviews, and got one offer.

I cannot reasonably wait until December to give them my answer. If I say no on the off-chance that I'll be hired in city A, then there was really no point in applying to city B. But if I say yes, can I still apply to the city A offers?

Would it be professionally acceptable to do interviews with other employers after accepting an offer already, and would it be ethical, if I get hired in my prefered location, to change my mind and tell the other company I won't be working for them after accepting their offer, considering I haven't worked with them yet and they have months to find someone else anyway? I wouldn't have wasted their money on training, which will happen if I go work with them and find a job in city A two years from now.

Furthermore, the current offer that I have to decide on are not hiring me for late-spring, as soon as I graduate, but for next September, because they said that they wouldn't have the resources to train me efficiently during the summer. Would getting a city A offer for May or June make a difference on the "is it acceptable" point?

EDIT: The country is Canada, if that makes a difference.

EDIT regarding the similar question. I am not asking whether I should keep looking, but whether I am allowed to without it looking bad. I want to apply to very specific jobs, and I had planned to before getting the offer. Furthermore, I wouldn't be looking "in case I get a better offer", but knowing fully well that any offer I would get would be better (because of the location), so I would want to take it.

Comment: @ChrisE The situation is different from that question, because of the very specific job hunting style in my field (all offers at the same time for a location), and the fact that I would not just continue looking at jobs overall, but instead apply to a few companies during a specific time frame as was my plan, not in the hopes of finding a better offer, but knowing that any offer from them would be better for me.

Comment: Furthermore, in my case, there's almost a full year before I would start at my current offer

Comment: Until you have signed a contract and agreed on a start date, there's no harm in going for other roles, just in case the first one doesn't work out.

Comment: @Kozaky Yes but, I will most likely sign a contract and agree to their conditions before December, I can't possibly post-pone it that long. so when December comes by, I will have done those things.

Comment: "the current offer that I have [is] for next September" - Today is October. Does this mean their offer is for you start in 11 months?

Comment: @Brandin Yes, for the reasons mentioned above. To be fair, I was looking for a job around may-june, not right now, so it's not *that* bad, but still not fun.

Comment: @KaitoKid Keep the job offer now for a month, and if nothing else comes up, accept it if you want. Next, if something else better should come up in the next few months, decide at that time what is the best thing to do.